# Why is the following function bijective?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is  the function  $f:\mathbb R→\mathbb R$ , $f(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ ، $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ , $f(1)=1$   bijective ?

I came up with the facts $f(0)=0$ & $f(n)=n$ & $f(\frac{m}{n}) =\frac{m}{n}$ for any integers $m,n$ where $n$ is not equal to zero , but it's not clear for me why should it be $f(x)=x$ for any real number x ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is f continuous ?

Comment: The only function with these properties is $f(x)=x$. "Is it bijective?" is a very strange question. Not giving source, motivation, your background with functional equations,... is strongly discouraged, here, as well as not showing even hints at own effort.

Comment: I came up with the facts  f(0)=0 & f(n)=n & f(m/n) =m/n for any  integers m,n where n is not equal to zero , but it's not clear for me why it's true for any real number x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've done some own research, after all. You're right, without the crucial property $$f\left(\frac1x\right)=\frac{f(x)}{x^2},\tag{1}$$ you couldn't know more than the function values at rational arguments, and there could be some rather wild (and not bijective) solutions. From the additive stuff, we'll just need $f(1+x)=1+f(x)$ and $f(1-x)=1-f(x)$. The rest is (sorry!) a bit tricky, but that's (for some people) the fascination of functional equations: Using (1), we get
$$f\left(\frac1{1+x}\right)=\frac{f(1+x)}{(1+x)^2}=\frac{1+f(x)}{(1+x)^2},$$
$$f\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)=1-f\left(\frac1{1+x}\right)=1-\frac{1+f(x)}{(1+x)^2}.$$ Using (1), again,
$$f\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)=\frac{f\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)}{\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^2}=\frac{(1+x)^2-1-f(x)}{x^2}.\tag2$$
On the other hand,
$$f\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)=f(1+1/x)=1+\frac{f(x)}{x^2}.\tag3$$
(2) and (3) together give
$$(1+x)^2-1-f(x)=x^2+f(x),$$ i.e. $$f(x)=x.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot . That was really helpful!